# Check if two columns of a data frame have same elements in different order in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
column1=[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]
column2=[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
column3=[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
column4=[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

here column2 and column3 is same as column1 but has different order
so i need a function that removes the columns that are duplicated by order
But column4 has consecutive two 1's and so doesn't match the order as in column1 or column2 or column3.
def dup_cols:
#remove cyclic ordered column values

Please help me with the function i need

Output i want is: Only column1 as other two columns are similar but different in order when compared to column2 and column3 but not in the case of column4 as it has two consecutive 1's.

Required output: column1[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]
column4[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]

As others are duplicate

Comment: How do you want the result to look?

Comment: The output i need is only column1: [0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]

Comment: I've update my answer

Comment: I have actually included another condition i need

Comment: Can anyone help me with my question???

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
def dup_cols(x,y):
    if x.sort()==y.sort():
        df.drop([y], axis=1, inplace=True)

list=df.columns
for i in range(len(list)-1):
    for k in range(i+1, len(list)):
        dup_cols(i,k)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get it done this way

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'column1':[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
'column2': [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
'column3': [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def dup_cols(col_to_compare): # function compares one column with others in the dataframe
    y = df #assign df to y
    m = sorted(y[col_to_compare]) #sort col_to_compare
    for k in y: #loop through all the keys of df except the column you want to compare
        if k == col_to_compare:
            pass
        else:
            l = sorted(y[k]) #sort k-th column
            if (m == l): #compare sorted col_to_compare and k-th column 
                y = y.drop(columns=[k]) #drop where comparison returns True
    print (y)

dup_cols('column1') #remove duplicates of column1
```

> Result

```
   column1
0        0
1        0
2        0
3        0
4        1
5        0
6        1
7        0
8        0
9        0
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want unique values, use a `set`

```py
columns = [
  column1, column2, ...
]

uniques = [set(col) for col in columns]
```

If you want exact same number of each elements, use a `collections.Counter`

```py
from collections import Counter

columns = [
  column1, column2, ...
]

counters = [Counter(col) for col in columns]
```

As far as you described your problem, the follow code works :

```py
from collections import Counter

if __name__ == "__main__":
    columns = [
        [0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
    ]

    counters = [Counter(col) for col in columns]

    df = []
    for counter in counters:
        if counter not in df:
            df.append(counter)

    print(df)
```

Outputs :

`[Counter({0: 8, 1: 2})]`